# What does the last row mean in classification_report in scikit learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I wonder what the last line which says avg / total mean in scikit-learn classification report? Is it macro average or micro average? For example in the following table taken from the documentation, what is the

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L1332), it is weighted average.

```
# compute averages
values = [last_line_heading]
for v in (np.average(p, weights=s),
          np.average(r, weights=s),
          np.average(f1, weights=s)):
    values += ["{0:0.{1}f}".format(v, digits)]
values += ['{0}'.format(np.sum(s))]
```

You can look at this [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4558), which suggests that they are going to include all average methods. But it is not ready yet.